# Increment field of another collection in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I created two collections,one for enterprise and another for employees,their schema is as follows,

```js
var mongoose= require('mongoose');

var Enterprise= new mongoose.Schema({
 
 name:{type:String},
 email:{type:String},
 sector:{type:String},
 employees: {type:Number,default:0}

});


module.exports={
 Enterprise:Enterprise
};
```

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var employee = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    enterprise:{type: String},
 name:{type:String},
 email:{type:String},
 password:{type:String},
 gender:{type:String},
});

module.exports = {

 employee:employee
};
```

my add employee route,

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var q = require('q');

var employee = mongoose.model('employee');
var enterprise = mongoose.model('enterprise');

var addEmployee = function(req, res) {

    newEmployee = new employee();

    newEmployee.enterprise = req.params.enterprise;
    newEmployee.name = req.params.name;
    newEmployee.email = req.params.email;
    newEmployee.gender = req.params.gender;

    function detailSave() {

        var deferred = q.defer();

        newEmployee.save(function(err, data) {

            if (err) {
                res.send(500);
                console.log('couldnt save employee details');
                deferred.reject({errmessage: 'couldnt save employee details', err: err});
            } else {

                res.send(200);
                deferred.resolve({data: data});
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function incrementEmployee(doc) {

        var deferred = q.defer();

        enterprise.findOneAndUpdate({ 'name': doc.enterprise }, { $inc: { 'employees': 1 } },

            function(err, num) {
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject({errmessage: 'couldnt incrementEmployee', err: err});
                    res.send(500);
                    console.log('couldnt incrementEmployee');
                } else {
                    res.send(200);
                    deferred.resolve({num:num});
                }
            });

        return deferred.promise;

    }

    detailSave()
        .then(incrementEmployee)
        .then(function(success) {
            console.log('success', success);
            res.json(200, success);
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            res.json(500, err);
        })
        .done();

};
module.exports = {
    addEmployee: addEmployee
};
```

The problem is when I add an employee, the employees field in enterprise collection doesn't increment

Comment: Can you check the value of `data` in deferred.resolve({
                    data: data
                });? And also check `doc` value in `incrementEmployee`function

Comment: { data: 
   { __v: 0,
     gender: 'male',
     email: 'ashok@gmail.com',
     name: 'ashok',
     enterprise: 'skydrive',
     _id: 57ecbf6bf0de631cf333dab5 } }
success { num: null }

Comment: it's your `doc` value in `incrementEmployee` method?

Comment: yes it is the doc value in incrementEmployee method

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is not working since `doc.enterprise` is `null` 
On the basis of your comment.

Try to give your `query` like this `{'name': doc.data.enterprise}`

```
function incrementEmployee(doc) {

  var deferred = q.defer();

  enterprise.findOneAndUpdate({
      'name': doc.data.enterprise
    }, {
      $inc: {
        'employees': 1
      }
    },

    function(err, num) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject({
          errmessage: 'couldnt incrementEmployee',
          err: err
        });
        res.send(500);
        console.log('couldnt incrementEmployee');
      } else {
        res.send(200);
        deferred.resolve({
          num: num
        });
      }
    });

  return deferred.promise;

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work as num contains the detail of the enterprise collection instead of employee.i changed the query to newEmployee.enterprise and it worked,thanks for pointing it out